# Django: way of getting objects?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-templates

I have following structure of models

For the model of 'Campaigns' I'm going to write down functions that would be called in a template: ads_count

My solution was:

```
class Campaigns(AlphaModel):
    Project = models.ForeignKey('Projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='projects')
    ......
    def ads_count(self):
       c = 0
       gr = AdGroups.objects.filter(Campaign=self).all()
       for g in gr:
          c += g.ads_count()
       return c
    ......

class AdGroups(AlphaModel):
    Campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='campaigns')
    server_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ......
    def ads_count(self):
       return Ads.objects.filter(AdGroup=self).count()

    ......
class Ads(AlphaModel):
    AdGroup = models.ForeignKey('AdGroups', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='adgroups_a')
    server_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    ......
```

However this was throws an error "Cannot resolve keyword into field"

Is there any simple and direct way of counting objects of 'ads' that belongs to particular object of 'campaigns' ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please post your model code - it isn't possible to understand how your models relate to each other without this. It looks like your filter arguments are wrong - you seem to be using class names instead of field names.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  That is just an exampe. Here is a real code:

`class Projects(AlphaModel):
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
....

class Campaigns(AlphaModel):
    Project = models.ForeignKey('Projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='projects')
....

class AdGroups(AlphaModel):
    Campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='campaigns')
....

class Ads(AlphaModel):
    AdGroup = models.ForeignKey('AdGroups', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='adgroups_a')
....`

Comment: So I want to get the amount of Ads that belong to Campaigns througth AdGroups

Comment: Please edit the question with the code - can't make any sense of it in a comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow) Thanks for patience! Updated the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is general convention to use CamelCase only for class definitions, and lower case in all your field names. This makes it much easier to follow the code and distinguish between classes and objects. I would rewrite your models as follows:

```
class Campaigns(AlphaModel):
    project = models.ForeignKey('Projects', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='projects')

class AdGroups(AlphaModel):
    campaign = models.ForeignKey('Campaigns', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='campaigns')
    server_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()

class Ads(AlphaModel):
    ad_group = models.ForeignKey('AdGroups', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='adgroups_a')
    server_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

Now, to get the count of `Ads` associated with a `Campaign`, you can do this query:

```
class Campaigns(AlphaModel):
    ...

    def ads_count(self):
        return Ads.objects.filter(ad_group__campaign=self).count(distinct=True)
```

(using your existing field names this would be):

```
Ads.objects.filter(AdGroup__Campaign=self).count(distinct=True)
```

Comment: It is also convention to use singular model names. `Campaigns` should be `Campaign` etc. Does one `Campaigns` object contain many campaigns? No. It is one Campaign. Eg `campaigns = Campaign.objects.all()`.